# Gulp task to delete empty files

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-process

When compiling TypeScript, I get a lot of empty JavaScript files generated because their TypeScript counterparts contain only interfaces. There's currently no `tsc` option to suppress generation of these files. I'm using the `gulp-tsc` plugin to compile.

Is there a plugin or some other means to clean up empty files, or even a more general purpose gulp plugin that would allow me to delete files based on their name and content? Or is there a way to do this in gulp without using plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could relatively easily use [`node-glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to look for matching files outside `gulp`, something like this:

```js
var glob = require('node-glob'),
    fs = require('fs);

gulp.task('delete-empty-files', function(cb) {
    glob('/path/to/generated/**/*.js', function(err, files) {
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            if(fs.statSync(file).size === 0) {
                fs.unlinkSync(file);
            }
        });
        // make sure the task runs asynchronously!
        cb();
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `gulp-tap` to achieve a similar result, like so:

```js
var tap = require('gulp-tap'),
    fs = require('fs);

gulp.task('delete-empty-files', function() {
    return gulp.src('/path/to/generated/**/*.js')
        .pipe(tap(function(file) {
            if(file.stat.size === 0) {
                fs.unlinkSync(file);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

They're pretty equal, really.  I think the first one will be faster, because it won't have the extra stuff from `gulp` and `vinyl-fs`.

You *might* be able to add the `{read: false}` options to `gulp.src()` to speed things up, but that might also disable the `.stat` from being read.  If you want to try it, you add it like this:

```js
return gulp.src('/path/to/files/**/*.js', {read: false}).pipe(...)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the comprehensive answer and for putting me onto `gulp-tap`.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer would be to just name those interface files with the .d.ts extension instead of .ts. No files are generated this way.

Comment: Yes, this is actually true in *some* cases. It just so happens that after much experimentation, I use external modules exclusively which allows me to put interfaces in .d.ts files. So +1 for you. Nevertheless, there may well be use cases for deleting empty files so I'd like to leave the currently accepted answer as accepted for the benefit of those arriving here from Google who are probably looking for a way to delete empty files rather than solve this TypeScript problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah - "A better answer for your specific use case". Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for anyone else facing similar issues, [`gulp-clip-empty-files`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clip-empty-files) solves this.

> Remove empty files from stream. This prevent errors on some other
>   plugins like gulp-sass and can be usefull removing placeholders.

The usage is quite simple...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clip = require('gulp-clip-empty-files');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/*.scss')
        .pipe(clip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

In this example all empty `.scss` files will be "clipped" (ignored?) before written out